# Type of tray to use to bake integrated circuits in DIY reflow oven

Tags: esd, reflow

I just recently started getting into surface mount components with a Controleo3 reflow oven. I usually buy extra components for projects I build, and end up with extra integrated circuits that have been taken out of their original vacuum sealed bag, and are past their MSL life.

I'd like to bake them in my reflow oven to remove moisture before doing a reflow, to use in future projects, but am not sure what the best material to use as a tray in the oven would be. I'm most concerned about ESD damage during baking.

Would glass be best? I saw one datasheet suggest using glass to bake ICs on, but I read elsewhere that it's not good from an ESD standpoint. Or would a spare, unpopulated PCB be better to place the components on during baking in the reflow oven? Or some other material? I've search the forums, and the internet in general, and couldn't find any advice for a tray to use for home-baking components (other than the advice that it may or may not even be necessary).

I also asked the developer of the Controleo3, but he said that he hasn't baked components in it before, but has heard of others doing it successfully. The oven does have a baking profile.

Comment: an extra pcb or pyrex dish would be fine.

Comment: If you can program your oven, just set it at 80°C and hold for some minutes while you preheat the board during your regular reflow run. No need to heat everything twice.  Also, if the humidity spec is to prevent oxidation, then there is no point to trying to "dry" anything. The damage is already done. Heating will only drive off excess water or humidity. Heating will not reverse oxidation.

Comment: I thought that the main issue was "popcorning" from moisture accumulating in the package material. Not sure that an extra-long preheat during the normal cycle will take care of that.

Comment: Packaging has come a long way in the last 10 years. I do not bother, I just place them then reflow them.The profile I use has a bit extra preheat time.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Based on this, I'll just use an extra pcb to bake the components. I realize it may not really be necessary, but I'd rather follow the manufacturer recommendation when it comes to MSL ratings.